# How do I check if a random variable follows the T Distribution?

Tags: r, t-distribution

Let us say I have a data for a random variable X -- Is there a convenient test that can tell me how well it fits the T distribution?

Code in R would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fit the parameters, and lot the **QQ-plot** or the **empirical density**, as explained here:

http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/probability.html

Additionally there are numerous tests explained here:

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf